# How to customize handleSubmit method of formikbag using react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to customize handleSubmit method of the formikbag using react.

I am calling handleSubmit on onSubmit method of a component. now before submitting I want to check if there are any errors. If errors show message "error cannot submit form" and if no errors then should submit form.

Below is my code,

```
const Parent = ()=> {
    const {errors,handleSubmit} = formikBag;

    return (
        <Wizard 
            onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    );
}
```

The above code works. Now I want to customise `handleSubmit` method such that I should check if any errors then show  notification with message "error and cannot submit form" otherwise submit form.

I have tried like below,

```
const onSubmit = {
    if (!isEmpty(errors) {
        notify({
            status: 'error',
            title: 'error and cannot submit form',
        });
    } else {
        handleSubmit(); // error here argument of 1 expected but got 0
    }
}

return (
    <Wizard onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
);
```

But I get error in the line where I call handleSubmit() argument of 1 expected but got 0. An argument for bypass not found.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`handleSubmit`](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik#handlesubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany) requires `values` param, but you have not passed that param to the function. Similarly, we have `values` in [`onSubmit`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany) too.

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
    if (!isEmpty(errors) {
        notify({
            status: 'error',
            title: 'error and cannot submit form',
        });
    } else {
        handleSubmit(values); // you need pass `values` here
    }
}

return (
    <Wizard onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
);
```